# how to pass class name to javascript function parameter

Tags: javascript, class, parameters

I am struggling on passing a class name (only number 11 and 22) as function parameter. The code is:

```
document.querySelector(".show-11-22,.show-11-33,.show-33-55,");
```

I want to pass the number from class `(.show-**11**-**22**,.show-**11**-**33**,.show-**33**-**55**)` to function parameter *number* and *size* respectively

```
function myData(number,size){
    //some code
}
myData(number,size)

//so that it would be like
myData(11,22)
myData(11,33)
myData(33,55)
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".show-11-22,.show-11-33,.show-33-5").forEach(function(e) { var c = e.className.split('-'); myData(c[1], c[2]) });`

Comment: `.querySelector('.ahow-'+ number + '-' + size)`. Also it would be easier for us if you tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: `.show-**11**-**22**` What are the `*` ? Any single character or the asterisk itself?